# NoSuchElementException When writng to file

Tags: java, file-io, exception, textinput

I am writing a program that read string and integers from file, then copy the data and write to another file. Data entries should be separated by a space.

My input should and output should follow the following format, the first two set of numbers are string while the others are integers:

123123 242323 09 08 06 44

I get **Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException** when I run my code, I do not know why

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Billing {



    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException  {

        //define the variables


        String callingnumber;
        String callednumber;
        String line;
        int startinghour;
        int startingminute;
        int endinghour;
        int endingminute;


        //open input and output files
        FileReader freader = new FileReader("BillingData.txt");
        BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(freader);


        FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter("BillingOutput.txt");
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter (fwriter);

        // set space between the numbers
         line=inFile.readLine();
         while(line!=null)
         {
             //creat a scanner to use space between the numbers
             Scanner space = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter(" ");


             callingnumber=space.next();
             callednumber=space.next();
             startinghour=space.nextInt();
             startingminute=space.nextInt();
             endinghour=space.nextInt();
             endingminute=space.nextInt();



            // writing data to file
             outFile.printf("%s %s %d %d %d %d", callingnumber, callednumber,startinghour, startingminute, endinghour, endingminute);

             line=inFile.readLine();



         }//end while

         //close the files
         inFile.close();
         outFile.close();


    }//end of mine


}//end of class
```

Comment: There is a blank field in your input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the scanner has run out of data in the line - probably because there are less than 6 values in it.  To avoid the error you should do something like this:

```
if (space.hasNextInt()) {
    startingHour = space.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Scanner is trying to read in a token that either doesn't exist or is of the wrong type. Myself, I'd split the String, line using " " as my delimiter and then deal with the array returned.